# ReactJS - render file name in text when selected file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Creating app to upload files from local directory, it was a successful for me. Until the part where I start add some styles and features, I've encounter some issues. after creating connection between `<input>` + `<label>`.

```
<input
  id="file"
  type="file"
  name="selectedFile"
  onChange={this.onChange}
/>
<label htmlFor="file">{file}</label>
```

The goal was to have text render on label tag instead of actual input following `onChange` event function.

Following ternary conditional with the `fileName` (from state) and `file`, they both are set at null as default. Since no file is been selected, the condition is set at false and text "Choose a file" will display on `<label>`.

```
render() {
  const { fileName } = this.state;
    let file = null;

    file = fileName 
      ? ( <span>File Selected - {fileName[0]}</span>) 
      : ( <span>Choose a file...</span> );
```

Anytime user select on `<label>` painted "Choose a file" text. it triggers `onChange` function to have file directory pop up at front of browser. Once file is selected from list, the condition becomes true. And should paint actual file name on `<label>` *eg **something.jpg***...

```
<label htmlFor="file">{file}</label>
```

I didn't get any, it wasn't successful for me... However, I've  strong suspect it has something to do with this syntax `fileName[0]`...

```
<span>File Selected - {fileName[0]}</span>)
```

I may have it wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Here's full syntax...

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
     fileName: '',
  };

  onChange = e => {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case 'fileName':
        this.setState({ fileName: e.target.files[0] });
      break;
      default:
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
     }
  };

render(){
   const { fileName } = this.state;
   let file = null;

   file = fileName 
      ? ( <span>File Selected - {fileName[0]}</span>) 
      : ( <span>Choose a file...</span> );

   return(
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
         <div>
            <input
               id="file"
               type="file"
               name="selectedFile"
               onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="file">{file}</label>
            </div>
        </form>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will say, I spent a whole lot of time trying to understand this code, and in particular the whole `Switch/Case` block of code.  Why is that there?  I didn't understand the input `onChange` event can return `id`, `type`, and `name`. Why does that matter?  Well it would allow you to update numerous elements in a single form with a single `onChange()` function, one form element per  `case`. This is awesome. Thx for sharing...

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question correctly, then it seems you're wanting the `<label />` to display the filename of the file that was selected by the user?

This can be achieved by using the `.name` property on the file asscoaited with the input's change event:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       fileName: '',
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {

    switch (e.target.name) {
      // Updated this
      case 'selectedFile':
        if(e.target.files.length > 0) {
            // Accessed .name from file 
            this.setState({ fileName: e.target.files[0].name });
        }
      break;
      default:
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
     }
  };

render(){
   const { fileName } = this.state;
   let file = null;

   file = fileName 
      ? ( <span>File Selected - {fileName}</span>) 
      : ( <span>Choose a file...</span> );

   return(
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
         <div>
            <input
               id="file"
               type="file"
               name="selectedFile"
               onChange={ (event) => this.onChange(event) }
            /> { /* Updated this to an arrow function */ }
            <label htmlFor="file">{file}</label>
            </div>
        </form>
     );
  }
}
```

For a working example, [see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puagr65v/) - hope that helps!

Comment: Darce Denny, the `.name` properties is it -- i have updated from `{file}` into `{file.name}` eg -> `<label htmlFor="file">{file.name}</label>`. Its now able to display file name in text.

Comment: @sirrus great! - did the jsFiddle I linked to work for you?

Comment: Yes, JSFiddle you shared worked for me -- this one got light blub lit in my head on `.name` property

Comment: @sirrus glad to hear that it helped :-)